# Flink unit test for state TTL expiry

Tags: java, testing, mockito, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to advance the processing time of my OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness so that the TTL expires

```
    Set<Integer> setA = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    Set<Integer> setB = new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(4));

    Mockito.when(configFetcher.getNumbers())
        .thenReturn(setA)
        .thenReturn(setB);
    OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<TypeA, TypeA> testHarness =
        new OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(new StreamFilter<>(filterA));
    testHarness.setup();
    testHarness.open();
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(testTimeMs);
    testHarness.setStateTtlProcessingTime(testTimeMs);

    // getNumbers() will be called for the first time here
    testHarness.processElement(elementA, testTimeMs);

    // expire the TTL
    long ttlExpireTimeMs = testTimeMs + Duration.ofMinutes(5).toMillis();
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(ttlExpireTimeMs);
    testHarness.setStateTtlProcessingTime(ttlExpireTimeMs);

    // getNumbers() called for second time only if state is empty. 
    // Assuming TTL will have expired, state will be empty meaning we fetch the setB. 
    // But the problem here is that the state is not clearing
    testHarness.processElement(elementB, ttlExpireTimeMs);
```

getNumbers() is called for the first time to populate the state but even after I advance the processing time, the state is not expiring and clearing. Therefore, the second getNumbers() is not being called to return setB. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State TTL only works for keyed streams, so I believe you need to use `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness`.